# Tesla coil construction

Tags: tesla-coil

I have constructed my tesla coil. But i couldn't find the MMC capacitors for the primary capacitor bank. So what is the alternative way of making capacitor bank? Are there any suitable capacitor types to do the job?

Comment: Possibly a double sided fiberglass PC board. Etch about 1.25" edge then apply HV doped the edge. It will have low inductance making it very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Search EBay for *[Door-knob Capacitors](http://www.ebay.com/itm/880pF-20KV-N4700-doorknob-capacitor-/390025441953?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5acf53f2a1)*. These are capacitors that are used in industrial semiconductor laser high voltage discharge systems. They are able to handle the voltages you will encounter in the Tesla coil primary circuit. You can usualy find some up for bid. The co-axial terminals are threaded and so you can use studs to create series arrangements to increase voltage capacity and gang the serial assemblies in parallel between sandwich metal plates (you'll have to cut and drill these yourself) to get the capacitance you need.

Answer (score 0):

Cornell dubilier 942C20P15K-F capacitors are what you want and available lots of places